# How can i replace Scroll Indicator(scroller) in uiscrollview with my image

Tags: iphone, uiscrollview

I want to replace vertical scroll Indicator in uiscrollview with my image.is there any way to do so.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

While that sounds like a bad idea, I think you could turn showsHorizontalScrollIndicator and showsVerticalScrollIndicator to NO, and then draw your own "during tracking." Oh, and override flashScrollIndicators. Probably a fair amount of work to get just right.